# Video subFolder is acting as my Hard Disk

Tags: windows

I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and everything seems to run fine, the problem is that I found duplicated folders on the pc like Documents, Pictures, etc. (This happened because on Windows 7 I moved those folders to my data drive and I suppose Windows 10 create them again.) I managed to fix this problem by moving the folders to the default location then moving them back to my data drive.

Everything was good, but I made a mistake and I did not create a Video folder on my data drive, I just put it on the root of my data drive. I have try to put it back with the .bat file to restore the locations but it put my hard drive as the video folder, when I tried to do it manually I get the error that I don't have privileges.

Attached are images further explaining the error.

[image: http://imgur.com/5mkAlX6]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your user profile folder. Right click on the video folder that is your `S:` drive and choose `Properties`. On the `Location` tab click `Restore to default`. When asked whether to move the data select `No`. Now you’re back to the default configurtion and can do whatever you wanted to do.